# Python function call in class

Tags: python, function, class

I would like to make a class that returns a pseudo random number generator. I want to save the result of the _rand function in _r but when I call the function _rand(int(time.time())) I get the error message "rand() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seed'". Could someone please explain me what I did wrong.

```
class PRNG:
import time
_m = 32768
_b = 9757 
_c = 6925
 
 def _rand(self, seed):
     n = seed % self._m
     while True:
         n = (n * self._b + self._c) % self._m
         yield n

_r = _rand(int(time.time()))
         
 def rand(self) :
     return self._r.__next__() 
        
prng = PRNG()
print(prng.rand())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code is properly formatted exactly as you have it. I can't tell how you actually intend for the code to be indented, and as you know, indentation is vital in Python.

Comment: That said: when you do `_r = _rand(int(time.time()))`, what exactly do you expect that to mean? In particular, are you trying to call the `_rand` **method** of the class? In that case, **which instance** of the class do you expect to be used? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_rand()` takes two arguments; `self` and `seed`. Specifically you need to provide what instance the method is being called on. Instead of what you have, try defining `_r` in a constructor

```
def __init__(self):
    self._m = 32768
    self._b = 9757 
    self._c = 6925
    self._r = self._rand(int(time.time()))
```